# android:clipChildren="false" Doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, layout, clip

I try to make the content of my ScrollView to overflow it wrapper layout bounds. Even setting android:clipChildren="false" to all his ancestor, doesn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/hideInputfocus"
android:clipChildren="false"         <!--Here-->
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:clipChildren="false"         <!--Here-->
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context="ch.bla.bla.activities.MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimension_name"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:clipChildren="false"         <!--And here-->
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/cp_scrollView">
    <!--android:background="@color/white"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"     <!--And here-->
        android:clipToPadding="false"    
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar_layout"
        >

        <!--<TextView-->
        <!--My overflowing textView
```

Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks

Comment: your relativelayout is itself cliped by its parent (probably a frame in the activity?)

Comment: Thanks, That's what I supposed but my first layout is the one called by setContentView(R.layout.myXml);. At least this Xml should appear clipped in the viewer preview right? it's not the case

Comment: @aiqency : have u solved this issue? how?

Comment: @Satpal Yadav unfortunately no